# With python installed from source can't install any package with pip (SSL module is not available)

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, ssl, pip, openssl

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.1 which comes whit its own python3.11, where pip works perfectly.
If I install other python versions through apt-get (`sudo apt-get install python3.10`) the related pip works perfectly.

But I just installed an alternative python version (3.7.9 ) from source (I'm not able to use apt for this python version), doing the following

```
cd usr/lib
sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.9/Python-3.7.9.tgz
sudo tar xzf Python-3.7.9.tg
cd Python-3.7.9
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
```

Python3.7 works fine, but if I try to install any package (using pip3.7 or, after creating a virtualenv based on python3.7, using pip) I get the following warning

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
```

Followed by the error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy
```

I'm sure I have Openssl installed because other versions of python don't give probelms with pip (also I can see ssl in the folder `/etc/ssl`) so the problem seems to be related only on a link between ssl and python **installed from source**.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hint 1: Avoid `sudo` when you don't really need it. You don't need `sudo` to download and compile, only need it for `make install`.

Comment: Hint 2: Watch output from `./configure`. Yes, it's large and mostly boring. But there're hidden gems in the pile. Especially watch problems with absent libraries.

Comment: Hint 3: To compile Python's `_ssl.so` module you need OpenSSL development files (headers and link libraries). I'm not 100% sure but I think you need `sudo apt install openssl-devel`. After that clean, reconfigure and recompile Python. Like this: `sudo chown -R $USER . && make distclean && ./configure && make && sudo make altinstall`

Comment: Sorry, it's `sudo apt install libssl-dev`

Comment: thanks, but in my case openssl was already installed but python compiled from source is not able to 'see' it (python installed from apt-get doesn't have this problem), I think I found a solution for my specific problem, I posted it below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it can help anyone, I found a solution:
before doing

```
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
```

I simply modified part of the file Modules/Setup.dist

from

```
# Socket module helper for SSL support; you must comment out the other
# socket line above, and possibly edit the SSL variable:
#SSL=/usr/local/ssl
# _ssl _ssl.c \
#    -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
#    -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

to

```
# Socket module helper for SSL support; you must comment out the other
# socket line above, and possibly edit the SSL variable:
SSL=/etc/ssl
_ssl _ssl.c \
    -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
    -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

Notice that /etc/ssl is the actual location where I have ssl installed.

After the file modification I than installed with

```
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
```

And now (after eventually upgrading pip and setuptools) pip works fine.

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.11.1 on Ubuntu 22.04.1, you do not need to modify any distribution files, just add `--with-openssl-rpath=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` to the ./configure command line.

The ssl & crypto libs are in that directory, and this ensures they're located at runtime

Note this assumes you're running on an x86_64 distro, I expect there's a similar directory on ARM.